# Two components overlap each other when screen size is reduced

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, grid

My site has a component (NavPanel) that consists of two components (a back button (BackToButton ) and a search field (SearchTextField )). With a standard screen size, they are positioned as they should be, but if the screen sizes are reduced, then these two components overlap each other.

The most optimal for me would be if, with a compressed screen size, the second component (SearchTextField ) will be located under the first (BackToButton ). Tell me how you can solve this problem?

```
    const Style = {
    paddingLeft: '8%',
    paddingRight: '8%',
    minHeight: '70px',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexWrap: 'nowrap',
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
}

export default function NavPanel() {
    
    return (
        <Grid container sx={Style}>
            <BackToButton />
            <SearchTextField />
           
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

Comment: Look into using media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

You didn't use the [grid](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#main-content) correctly.

See the forked snippet [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-moser-5svxc1?file=/src/Filter.jsx).

---

**EDIT 1**

A:

[image: A]

B:

[image: B]

---

**EDIT 2**

You can change the breakpoint from `sm` to `md`. It means that `PageNameBackToButton` and `FilterButtonSearchTextField` will be stacked earlier, but A will not happen.

See the forked snippet [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-fog-hss204?file=/src/Filter.jsx).

**PageNameBackToButton.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Tooltip } from "@mui/material";
import BackToButton from "./BackToButton";

const PageName = {
  color: "#000000",
  fontSize: "20px",
  fontWeight: "700",
  letterSpacing: "0.2px",
  paddingRight: "20px"
};

const PageNameBackToButtonContainerStyle = {
  width: "50%",
  justifyContent: "start",
  alignContent: "center"
};

export default function PageNameBackToButton(props) {
  return (
    <div sx={PageNameBackToButtonContainerStyle}>
      <BackToButton />
      <div style={{ marginTop: "5px", display: "inline-block" }}>
        <span style={PageName}>Some Text</span>
        <span>
          <Tooltip title={`Here long long text`} placement="right">
            <span
              style={{ fontSize: "18px", color: "#ef1400", userSelect: "none" }}
            >
              Live
            </span>
          </Tooltip>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**FilterButtonSearchTextField.jsx**

```
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";

const FilterButtonSearchTextFieldContainerStyle = {};

const SearchTextField = {};

export default function FilterButtonSearchTextField() {
  return (
    <div sx={FilterButtonSearchTextFieldContainerStyle}>
      <TextField
        required
        label="Search Search"
        size="small"
        style={SearchTextField}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Filter.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";
import FilterButtonSearchTextField from "./FilterButtonSearchTextField";
import PageNameBackToButton from "./PageNameBackToButton";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const FilterContainerStyle = {};

const Root = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
  [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  }
}));

export default function Filter(props) {
  const pageName = props.pageName !== undefined ? props.pageName : "";
  const showBackToButton =
    props.showBackToButton !== undefined ? props.showBackToButton : false;

  return (
    <Grid container spacing={2} sx={FilterContainerStyle}>
      <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
        <PageNameBackToButton
          showBackToButton={showBackToButton}
          pageName={pageName}
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
        <Root>
          <FilterButtonSearchTextField table={props.table} />
        </Root>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the work you have done. This is the best fit for what I'm looking for. I would just like to clarify a small nuance: at the moment everything works correctly when resizing the browser. But the bottom line is that my site has a sidebar on the left, and if the browser is reduced in size and I open the sidebar, then the problem does not disappear. Is it somehow possible to solve at the moment or not?

Comment: I think we can figure this out. Can you please make a CodeSandbox snippet? I don't understand what happens when you open the sidebar.

Comment: I edited my answer. Do you mean A or B (see my edit)? Hm, for a small viewport it will be impossible to fit everything in one line. I see two possibilities: 1) You make a sidebar width in a relative unit, but it means that the content in the sidebar might be pushed to a new line as the viewport is getting smaller (depends on the content). This way you can have everything in a single line, but you "sacrifice" the sidebar's width. 2) You make a new design for smaller devices.

Comment: Ultimately, I would like to see the result as in photo B. That is, when the screen size changes, the PageNameBackToButton component remains intact. And when there was not enough space, the FilterButtonSearchTextField component immediately moved to the next line (without breaking the PageNameBackToButton component)

Comment: So, you don't want A to happen?

Comment: @ Yes you are right.

also about small screens: don't worry, because if the screen is small, the sidebar opens in full screen

Comment: I edited my answer. Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: I understand your explanations. Thank you very much for your help. You are a very good person and programmer.

Comment: Huh, this is the best thing I've ever heard on SO. Thank you for the kind words, wish you all the best. :)

Comment: Nice :)) This one became a lovely thread.

Answer (score 1):

`<Grid container>` is meaningless without some `<Grid item>`s inside it.

Just like the Bootstrap,

> The grid creates visual consistency between layouts while allowing flexibility across a wide variety of designs. Material Design's responsive UI is based on a 12-column grid layout.

Your code would be like this:

```
<Grid container spacing={1} sx={Style}>
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
    <BackToButton />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
    <SearchTextField />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I strongly recommend reading the [MUI Grid Docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/).

Comment: I thank you for your advice, but unfortunately this did not fix the error

Comment: I think `flexWrap: 'nowrap'` is disturbing the grids. Remove that line and see if the problem persists.